# How can I force a GridSearchCV model (or a pipeline model) to use a given hyparameter value?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, gridsearchcv

I have used GridSearchCV to find the best hyperparameters of a regularized logistic model.
It also includes a pipeline to impute and standardize the covariates.

```
numeric_cols = X_train.select_dtypes(include=['float64', 'int']).columns.to_list()
cat_cols = X_train.select_dtypes(include=['object', 'category']).columns.to_list()
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())
])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'))
])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('numeric', numeric_transformer, numeric_cols),
    ('cat', categorical_transformer, cat_cols)
], remainder='passthrough')

completo = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("preprocessor", preprocessor),
    ("classifier", LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', penalty='l2', 
    max_iter=100, class_weight='balanced'))
])

params = {'classifier__C': np.logspace(-4, 16, 21, base=1.5)}

grid_search_lr2 = GridSearchCV(completo, params, scoring='roc_auc')

results_lr2 = grid_search_lr2.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Up to here it works.

Now I can use the fitted model to make predictions, and it will automatically use the best tuned parameters.

```
grid_search_lr2.predict(X_test)
```

But, what if instead I want to force it to use a manually chosen value for the hyperparameters instead of the **best** ones. For example C=0.5. Maybe this is not possible if I don't retrain the model.

What I want to retrain the model with the whole train data (without CV) and keep the hyperparameters but change one?

I have tried with the option `C=0.5` but it produces this error: (no matter if I use completo or results_lr2)

```
Pipeline.fit does not accept the C parameter.
```

I have also tried with the option `classifier__C=0.5` but it produces this error:

```
LogisticRegression.fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'C'.
```

How can I tell the model (which includes the pipeline) to use a particular C value?
What if I want to specify that C values but keep the other best values for the other hyperparameters (I know in my example I have just one).

Do I need to create a new pipeline or can I reuse the old one, completo?

Comment: Your model is trained based on your parameters. It would be more logical to retrain your model based on the new parameters you set. You may get the best parameters from the trained model in grid_search and change that one single parameter you want to change. That again would also not be very useful since the other parameters would no longer be the best parameters for your set parameter. I recommend retraining everything based on the C you set.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

The problem was I was trying to pass the hyperparameter through fit(), but I need to pass it before.

```
results_lr3 = completo.set_params(classifier__C=0.5).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

It works, but the problem now is it leaves the original pipeline, completo, modified.

Comment: You could clone the pipeline before fitting it to avoid modifying the original. The search's `best_estimator_` was cloned before fitting it, so otherwise your original pipeline should remain unfitted.